# Adding file extension via htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, file-extension

Is it possible to add .html to url that don't contain a file extension.  So for example

mydomain.com/somepage
will direct to
mydomain.com/somepage.html

I've tried using the following but get an internal server error.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: [Mon Apr 02 10:16:52 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] mod_rewrite: maximum number of internal redirects reached. Assuming configuration error. Use 'RewriteOptions MaxRedirects' to increase the limit if neccessary.

Comment: FURL are running on the site, so not sure if this makes a diff?  I've made sure this comes before any FURL code

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# add .html file extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L]
```

It will only rewrite if such file with .html extension does exist (safe rewrite -- will solve your "maximum number of internal redirects reached" issue). In other words: if `/about` is requested and `/about.html` exists, then it will be rewritten. On another hand, if `/yeahbaby` is requested but no `/yeahbaby.html` file exists, then nothing will happen (404 handler should kick in .. or whatever other rule you may have there).

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  I'm not getting the error anymore but it's not actually doing the rewrite

Comment: Works perfectly here (Apache 2.2.xx on Windows) .. and worked fine on other similar (if not identical) questions (search for "how to add .php extension" or something like that). If it does not work then more details are required -- how much control do you have over Apache? Can you enable rewrite debugging http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging ?